# Applying textbf and ttfamily simultaneously

Tags: fonts, bold

I'm trying to apply `textbf` and `ttfamily` simultanously, but the font is only getting monospaced and not bold.

Example:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Testing}
\textbf{Bold}\\
\ttfamily{Monospaced}\\
\textbf{\ttfamily{Bold and Monospaced}}\\
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

How can I make the output become monospaced and bold at the same time?

Comment: The standard Computer Modern fonts don't have a boldface monospaced type. The Latin Modern fonts do, and they also have a lighter version for medium, that can be activated with `\usepackage[lighttt]{lmodern}`. Give it a try.

Comment: `\ttfamily` acts like a switch.  So, `\ttfamily{A}B` effects both the `A` and the `B`.  To limit the effect of `\ttfamily` you need to enclose it in parentheses.

Comment: @egreg, it worked, if you want to write as a answer, i'll mark as solved

Comment: I beleive that it's not a duplicate, since is a different solution and I'm not using listings.

Comment: @FranciscoSokol It's really the same: `\ttfamily` and `\bfseries`. Using `listings` is incidental. As I often say, closing as duplicate is not a judgment on the questioner, but rather a way to keep information more compact and useful for future readers.

Comment: @egreg -- your suggestion to use `\usepackage[lighttt]{lmodern}` isn't clearly presented in the cited reference, and it would make a much better answer if it were.  a logical place to add it there would be in Ulrike's answer, but that would make nonsense out of some of the comments.  i'm all for enhancing and consolidating, but i think this one is a bit tricky.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I added an answer there: it was clearly missing.

Comment: @egreg -- okay.  +1 there, and vote to close, and hope enough other people notice to kick the new answer up from the bottom.